# How to render a template from within a module?

Tags: templating, craft3, modules

I'm currently developing a module that contains a custom field and I'd like to create a template to be used in the `getInputHtml` method.

I try using the `Craft::$app->view->renderTemplate` method to render a template in the "resources" folder of my module, but Craft does not seem to find the template. How should I specify the path to the template from this module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include your template roots [Enhancing a Craft CMS 3 Website with a Custom Module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module#2-the-module-class)

```
public function __construct($id, $parent = null, array $config = [])
{
    Craft::setAlias('@modules/sitemodule', $this->getBasePath());
    $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\sitemodule\controllers';

    // Base template directory
    Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, function (RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
        if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'templates')) {
            $e->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
        }
    });

    // Set this as the global instance of this module class
    static::setInstance($this);

    parent::__construct($id, $parent, $config);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robin for your swift reply. I've added the code to the main module file, but I'm not sure what path I should use to render the template. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If your module is called `my-module` in your bootstrap file and contains a file `modules/my-module/src/templates/fields/myField.twig` the path will be `my-module/fields/myField.twig`